# Is there a way to omit NaN in AmCharts line series without line going through value zero (0)?

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

Is there a chance to skip/omit the NaN values in AmChart4. The line is not correct as soon as there is some data missing in the dataset. In this case the line goes thought value 0, instead of simply connecting at next known value. Or at least disconnect at point where NaN appears. I tried `series.connect = false`, but it did not results as I expected.

[Reproducible example here](https://jsfiddle.net/L8abzx1o/1/#&togetherjs=mQOQ7GHn3c)

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to skip those values is to remove them from the array. You can use the `beforedatavalidated` event to remove NaN values before the chart uses them:

```
chart.events.on("beforedatavalidated", function(ev) {
  let source = ev.target.data;
  let data = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
    let row = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(source[i]));
    data.push(row);
    if (isNaN(row.series1)) {
        row.series1 = undefined;
    }
    if (isNaN(row.series2)) {
        row.series2 = undefined;
    }
  }
  ev.target.data = data;
});
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r6180xs4/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the updated fiddle. Is there a way to skip categories without data?

I could skip first two categories with `zoomToCategories`, with disabling  Zooming out. Any better idea to avoid NaN categories??

`chart.events.on("inited", function zoomAxis() { categoryAxis.zoomToCategories("2010", "2019"); });`

```js
// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
chart.paddingTop = 20;


// Add data
chart.data = [
 {
  "datum": "2008",
  "indeks_placana": NaN,
  "indeks_neplacana": NaN
 },
 {
  "year": "2009",
  "series1": NaN,
  "series2": NaN
 },
 {
  "year": "2010",
  "series1": 100,
  "series2": 100
 },
 {
  "year": "2011",
  "series1": 102,
  "series2": 97
 },
 {
  "year": "2012",
  "series1": 102,
  "series2": 95
 },
 {
  "year": "2013",
  "series1": 114,
  "series2": 95
 },
 {
  "year": "2014",
  "series1": 154,
  "series2": 100
 },
 {
  "year": "2015",
  "series1": 155,
  "series2": 103
 },
 {
  "year": "2016",
  "series1": 154,
  "series2": 103
 },
 {
  "year": "2017",
  "series1": 152,
  "series2": NaN
 },
 {
  "year": "2018",
  "series1": NaN,
  "series2": 96
 },
 {
  "year": "2019",
  "series1": 151,
  "series2": 99
 }
];

// Create axes
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "year";


var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());


// Create series
function createAxisAndSeries(field, name, opposite, bullet) {
    
  var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
  series.dataFields.valueY = field;
  series.dataFields.categoryX = "year";
  series.strokeWidth = 2;
  series.yAxis = valueAxis;
  series.connect = false;
  series.name = name;
  series.tooltipText = "{name}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
  series.tensionX = 0.8;
  
  var interfaceColors = new am4core.InterfaceColorSet();
  
  switch(bullet) {
    case "triangle":
      var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());
      bullet.width = 12;
      bullet.height = 12;
      bullet.horizontalCenter = "middle";
      bullet.verticalCenter = "middle";
      
      var triangle = bullet.createChild(am4core.Triangle);
      triangle.stroke = interfaceColors.getFor("background");
      triangle.strokeWidth = 2;
      triangle.direction = "top";
      triangle.width = 12;
      triangle.height = 12;
      break;
    case "rectangle":
      var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());
      bullet.width = 10;
      bullet.height = 10;
      bullet.horizontalCenter = "middle";
      bullet.verticalCenter = "middle";
      
      var rectangle = bullet.createChild(am4core.Rectangle);
      rectangle.stroke = interfaceColors.getFor("background");
      rectangle.strokeWidth = 2;
      rectangle.width = 10;
      rectangle.height = 10;
      break;
    default:
      var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
      bullet.circle.stroke = interfaceColors.getFor("background");
      bullet.circle.strokeWidth = 2;
      break;
  }
  
  valueAxis.renderer.line.strokeOpacity = 1;
  valueAxis.renderer.line.strokeWidth = 2;
  valueAxis.renderer.line.stroke = series.stroke;
  //valueAxis.max =  14;
  valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = series.stroke;
  valueAxis.renderer.opposite = opposite;
  valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = false;


}
chart.events.on("beforedatavalidated", function(ev) {
  let source = ev.target.data;
  let data = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
    let row = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(source[i]));
    data.push(row);
    if (isNaN(row.series1)) {
        row.series1 = undefined;
    }
    if (isNaN(row.series2)) {
        row.series2 = undefined;
    }
  }
  ev.target.data = data;
});

// this is a method which will be called after the event is fired:
chart.events.on("inited", function zoomAxis() {
  categoryAxis.zoomToCategories("2010", "2019");
});

chart.zoomOutButton.disabled = true;

createAxisAndSeries("series1", "Series 1", true, "");
createAxisAndSeries("series2", "Series 2", true, "");


// Add legend
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();


// Create vertical scrollbar and place it before the value axis
chart.scrollbarY = new am4core.Scrollbar();
chart.scrollbarY.parent = chart.leftAxesContainer;
chart.scrollbarY.toBack();

// Create a horizontal scrollbar with previe and place it underneath the date axis
//chart.scrollbarX = new am4charts.XYChartScrollbar();
//chart.scrollbarX.series.push(series);
//chart.scrollbarX.parent = chart.bottomAxesContainer;
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Avoid to ask question in the answer post itself? Suggestions or queries regarding asked questions must be maintained in the comment section. Answer post meant for solving the question only.

Comment: ask questions only in comments rather then posting answer